# Rails debugger: input invisible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

On occasion, when execution is paused and passed to the debugger, the input (the things you, the person debugging, are typing) is not visible while you type.  The actual input is there, and becomes visible when you press Enter, and the debugging commands are processed just fine.  But, because your typing is not shown, it is troublesome to work with the readline prompt, because you can't see typos, you can't see the cursor to move it to a particular character, you can't see what's shown when you press the up arrow to go back in the readline history.

How can this be prevented or repaired?

Comment: I've seen this too but never worked out why - do you have the `rb-readline` gem installed?

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: @Charles: By all means, I want to do the right thing here, but in every site I've ever visited or used that offered a tagging system, adding more relevant tags was always desirable and beneficial, because it ensured that those that were searching in that general area of knowledge would have a greater chance of finding what they would soon discover would be a relevant and informative entity on the site (be that a photo, a video, an audio file, a blog entry, a question).

Comment: If Stackoverflow encourages a different system and intent for tagging, I'm happy to conform, but I must say I find the UX divergence striking.

Comment: If there is a FAQ or such detailing this policy, please direct me to a URL.  Thanks!

Comment: @Pistos, [here's a FAQ on Meta discussing how to tag questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18878/135887).  More tags aren't bad, but using tags as keywords or using tags as a summary of the question (input, invisible, disappears) is bad.